# Change UIPopoverController on the fly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

one UIPopoverviewController is currently visible....
its ViewController contains a button and clicking on the button changes the PopoverviewController's viewController to some other viewController.

Works great, viewController changed Successfully......
but PopoverViewController's contentsize is still same

lets change the contentSize manually
Step1 : View Controller changed
Step2 : popoverviewController.popovercontentSize = CGSizeMake(500,500);

:( Still No change in Size

NOTE: Both the View Controller loading successfully and if contentsize of popover is big enough to hold both then both viewController is Visible....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIViewController contentSizeForViewInPopover]` is read only once - when the popover is shown. You can look at it as the initial value for the popover controller's size.

However, once the popover is shown, it won't ever be read again, even if you change the `contentViewController`.
 You have to use `[UIPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:animated:]` instead.

```
UIPopoverController* popover = [... already existing and visible popover ...];
UIViewController* newPopoverContents = [... new content for the popover ...];

[popover setPopoverContentSize:newPopoverContents.contentSizeForViewInPopover
                      animated:YES];
[popover setContentViewController:newPopoverContents 
                         animated:YES];
```

Comment: if the popoverview is visible, doing something in the popover can change its size or not without making it invisible and visible again? .....its not changing for me

Comment: @ancode Added code confirmed to be working. If it doesn't work for you, your problem can lie somewhere else.

Comment: :) got it The Mistake was i changing the view controller first then setting the size.....changing the size first made its working...:)